# Ember {{#each}} helper not rendering

Tags: ember.js, each, helper

I am fairly new to web development and I was trying to walk through the ember doc examples. Everything was working ok until I tried to use the {{#each}} helper. I don't see what I am doing wrong, am I using the right version of handlebars?

Here is inside my html:

```
<div>First element</div>
<div id="second-placeholder"></div>
<div>Third element</div>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="second-item-template">
    {{#each App.egosController}}
        <h3>{{name}}</h3>
        <p>{{id}} - {{type}}</p>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

And here is my controller:

```
App.egosController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    init: function(){
        alert('Controller Initialised!');
    }
});

App.egosController.set('content', [ego, alterEgo]);

Ember.View.create({
    templateName: 'second-item-template'
}).appendTo('#second-placeholder');
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/VqgMk/64/

Thanks,

Ren

Comment: take a look at your JS console: `ego` is not defined. It works if you replace `ego` with `myEgo`

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out, it's been a long day and I thought I tried everything....

Comment: I've made an answer from the comment above. Glad to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `ego` is not defined. Just replace `ego` with `myEgo` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As louiscoquio pointed out, my ego variable was not initialised. I guess I'll use the console next time.